# Bulk modify DNS zones (dnscmd.exe)?

Tags: windows, windows-server-2003, domain-name-system

OK I'm failing badly here.  I have a standalone (non-AD) server running DNS for around 50 zones, so any "simple" operation like modifying MX or SOA records isn't simple.

I know of dnscmd however it doesn't seem to have an option to let you specify "all zones" when adding/deleting records?

There does seem to be a (relatively) undocumented "..AllZones" feature, but this only seems to work with certain switches from what I can tell.

So let's say I want to simply add a new MX record to all domains, I don't seem able to do so unless I specifically write a batch file containing all the individual zone names.

Any ideas would be much appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are ok using a batch file to do the work, you can use the FOR command to loop through all the files in the folder (or a subset of files depending on the parameters you use) to do the work.

```
FOR /F %%a (`dir /b c:\windows\system32\dns\ *.dns`) DO YourCommandGoesHere
```

I didn't test the command so the syntax may not be quite right.